# Stanford NLP Server initialization started providing "Error: Could not find or load main class" after months of use with no changes

Tags: stanford-nlp, stanford-nlp-server

I've been using the NLP server in a work project. I run it remotely on a linux server, and initialize the server as described in the documentation using the command:

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer [port] [timeout]
```

I worked on the project for about 3 weeks, the majority of the time I would initialize the server and leave it running, usually until I got disconnected from the remote machine. Today I went to initialize the server, and got the error in the title. As a check, I downloaded and unzipped the files to try to run locally, and got the same error. I'm going a bit crazy as I changed nothing, aside from getting disconnected during a work meeting yesterday, but certainly didn't move any files around or anything like that.

Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What directory are you running the command from?

Comment: I'm running the command from the directory that houses all of the Stanford NLP files.